# Import Images from the external Server in magento 2.3

Tags: magento, magento2, magento-2.3

Does anyone know how to send the external image URL into the database from the CSV import file in magneto 2.3? I tried those image types (base_image, small_image, thumbnail_image, or additional_images) but they didn't work for me.
I don't want to make a copy of the server image and save that copied link as a local server URL. I want to save the external server image URL into the database.

Comment: Do you mean you'd like to store the binary image data inside the database?

Comment: not really, I just want to save the external URl path in the database instead of the local path.